# MySQL Priority to Single Row of Type X

Tags: mysql

I have a select statement as follows that I want to give priority to a single row of type X. For example, I want the query to select as indicated, but put a result with "type = X" first. For example, my basic query would be:

```
SELECT id,type,rank
FROM stores
WHERE zip = "11217"
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

This would return:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | type | rank |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |   1  |  10  |
+----+------+------+
|  2 |   5  |   9  |
+----+------+------+
|  3 |   4  |   8  |
+----+------+------+
|  4 |   3  |   7  |
+----+------+------+
|  5 |   3  |   6  |
+----+------+------+
|  6 |   1  |   5  |
+----+------+------+
```

However, I would want to return just the top 3 results which would be:

```
SELECT id,type,rank
FROM stores
WHERE zip = "11217"
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 3;

+----+------+------+
| id | type | rank |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |   1  |  10  |
+----+------+------+
|  2 |   5  |   9  |
+----+------+------+
|  3 |   4  |   8  |
+----+------+------+
```

Now I would want to return the best row (ordered by rank descending) where type = 3, followed by the other rows, ranked normally by rank. This would result in:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | type | rank |
+----+------+------+
|  4 |   3  |   7  |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |   1  |   10 |
+----+------+------+
|  2 |   5  |   9  |
+----+------+------+
```

I know that I could do this with a UNION, but in my actual query, the rank is very expensive to calculate (includes multiple decay and distance functions). So I'm trying to see if there is any way to return the above results in a single query.

Comment: What happens with the row with `id = 1`? Shouldn't the result set contain the rows with IDs 4, 1 and 2?

Comment: You are right, I've corrected the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it easier to run two queries?

Comment: Doing so would cause the program run time to double to over 5 hours, so I'm trying to look to a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `order by`:

```
SELECT id, type, rank
FROM stores
WHERE zip = '11217'
ORDER BY (type = 3) DESC,
         rank DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

MySQL treats a boolean as an integer in a numeric context, with 1 being true and 0 being false.  TO get the "true" values first, `DESC` is needed after the condition.

EDIT:

If you have multiple rows with `id = 3` and you only want one, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.type, s.rank
FROM stores s cross join
     (select min(s.id) as id3 from stores s where type = 3) s3
WHERE zip = '11217'
ORDER BY (s.id = sd.id3) DESC,
         rank DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

This is the same idea, but you need to calculate the `id` that you are using.

Comment: @AvinashBabu . . . It is not assigning a value to anything.  It is doing a comparison.

Comment: But wouldn't this result in all rows with type = 3 appearing first? I was hoping to just force the first result to have type = 3 and to allow the rest of the result the rank naturally via the query.